# Codemirror. Is there a way to disable editing of specific part of code?

Tags: javascript, json, codemirror

In my project users can edit some json files. I'm using codemirror to give this ability to them. Everything working grate, except that sometimes they may edit json totally wrong, which can cause some problems.
I decided, to prevent users to edit keys in json and not give them ability to add/remove pairs. They can just edit existing values.

So, how can I establish this behavior with codemirror?

Thanks.

Comment: You can validate the Json from code mirror using **Linter**. 

Look into this  https://codemirror.net/demo/lint.html . You can validate the json ... Just an idea think about that.

Comment: @vinodh, thanks, but I can't see how linting can help me here, since I want prevent users to edit keys at all, not just show them that they doing something wrong.

Comment: you can prevent the edit inside the code mirror editor.. please look into that... read from document file.

Answer (score 0):

You could set everything but the parts they are allowed to edit read-only using the [`markText`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) method (but that still won't prevent people from entering closing quotes and such -- you could try a `"beforeChange"` handler with some clever logic for that, if you really want to).

Comment: Thanks Marijn, I will try that. Hope it'll help)